# Capture Sound in C# using .Net Own libraries nothing else

Tags: c#, audio, naudio, directsound

I'm trying to capture Microphone sound using C#, and i have searched Google for this thing and all what i am getting is non .Net Libraries , i only get open source ones Like `NAudio` and other like `DirectX` and `DirectX.DirectSound` which are for managed languages like C# but that is not what I'm looking for. and i have tried them both and i used this open source project as a reference in `NAudio`
http://voicerecorder.codeplex.com/
and i manged to capture sound and then output it on a speaker or a headphone but i am still having problems when saving the `Wav` file
but i was wondering is there any .Net Built in libraries that can help me with my objective ?
Thanks for your help in advance :)

Comment: I've attempted to do something similar in the past and it is pretty difficult.  I don't believe that you can do this using built in .Net libraries to accomplish this.  You are going to need a lower level library.

Comment: @tkcsam thank you but can you point me to some libraries that can preform these tasks in some ease :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> i was wondering is there any .Net Built in libraries that can help me
>   with my objective ?

**Short answer: No, at least not at the present time.**

The .NET framework does not provide any direct support for recording audio.  This is the reason libraries like nAudio exist.  You would neeed to use [Com Interop and the Windows API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743847%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to acheive this, and it would be no small task.  Even the [Coding4Fun article on recording sounds at Microsoft's Channel 19 website](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/NET-Voice-Recorder) uses NAudio.  Your best bet would be to follow their example.